# Azure Active directory reply address not same

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am getting error message below after I deploy my app on a new environment.

```
{
  "error":"invalid_client",
  "error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://xxxx/' does not match the reply address 'https://xxxx' provided when requesting Authorization code.\r\nTrace ID: d3f9a8ba-cadd-491c-a983-a56230f95900\r\nCorrelation ID: 9666214a-74f9-444c-92b6-edc8d42ec383\r\nTimestamp: 2018-04-25 10:00:49Z",
  "error_codes":[70002,50011],"timestamp":"2018-04-25 10:00:49Z",
  "trace_id":"d3f9a8ba-cadd-491c-a983-a56230f95900",
  "correlation_id":"9666214a-74f9-444c-92b6-edc8d42ec383"
}
```

I checked the ReplyURL and it is correctly set as https://xxxx.
In config the ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri  is https://xxxx/

Url used for navigation is https://xxxx

Does anyone know where it is retrieving the http://xxxx ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, which it seems that you have noticed, is that one url has a trailing backslash (`/`), while the other does not.

The reply url for authentication must match exactly what is registered on the app, therefore the trailing backslash (`/`) must be included everywhere.

Note that a trailing slash may be added to your reply url depending on the libraries and variable format used for storing that value.

For example:

```
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> $redirectUri = New-Object system.uri("https://myreply")
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> $redirectUri.AbsoluteUri
https://myreply/
```

I would just use the trailing slash everywhere you have your reply url to avoid this issue.